# sendmail (Smart Host) authentication with server using certificates

Tags: sendmail, certificate-authority

We are trying to prepare a setup with following configuration:

We have a Central mail server which acts as a gateway to the internet for our domain.

We have some client machines which access internet via a box running sendmail setup as SMART HOST with authentication enabled to communicate with the server.

This is working fine now.

I have been asked to explore the option of authentication via certificates and keys in sendmail. I have been told that the user might want to provide certificates instead of Auth Info.

I know that sendmail.cf has an option of providing certificates. But...
Is this possible/required? 
or is this another method of client-server communication in case of sendmail? 
Will login id and password not be required with Certificates?

Would appreciate if someone can provide answers to these questions and resolve these doubts.

Regards

Comment: Found a good article on [sendmail](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=starttls&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=OpenBSD+Current&arch=i386&format=html) with certificates (for STARTTLS), but looks like its for the server and not for the client which in my case i need configured on the box.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at cf/README file in Sendmail distribution/tarball. [Section `STARTTLS` Subsection `Relayng`]

Online version from sendmail-8.12.3 :
http://www.sendmail.org/~ca/email/doc8.12/cf/m4/starttls.html#relaying

Comment: So certificates are required only in the case of STARTTLS support? When sendmail client is trying to communicate with the SMTP MTA server, then these would be required?

Comment: In this case of authentication (certificates), do we also need to specify the UserName and Passwords for client-server authentication?

Comment: As I understand you may allow relaying based only on certificates presented by the client. BTW sendmail can accepts smtps connections (SMTPS = SMTP over SSL to port 465)

Comment: How do i achieve this "may allow relaying based only on certificates presented by the client". Can you please provide link to articles on configuring sendmail client server using certificate base auth. Looking to use only server authentication.

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: It is hard for me to think about _short_ update.

Comment: Please guide on how to do this.